# Compiling multiple .jar files with .java class

Tags: java, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I currently have a java class which I am attempting to compile using **Linux terminal** along with a folder (/libs) which contains about 9 .jar folders.
I am struggling trying to attempt this.
I am aware of how to compile a single library to a class:

```
javac -classpath /libs/example.jar MyMainClass.java
```

just unsure of how this can apply to multiple libraries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either refer to an entire folder containing all the libraries such as `javac -cp lib\* MyMainClass.java`

Alternatively, you can refer individual libraries as such: `javac -cp lib1\Library.jar;lib2\Library.jar MyMainClass.java` (separate with semicolon)

Comment: Thanks for the response, worked well. 
Turned out I was using: 
`import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.* `
thus why compiler was not working. fixed it though.